# Get child menu from NavigationView

Tags: android, menu, navigation, nested, drawer

In the menu of my NavigationView in the drawer I have nested menu:

```
<item android:title="View options">
        <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:title="Gallery"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:checked="true"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="Slideshow"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:checked="false"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

I know how to get to a standard menu item in one of the callback method for DrawerLayout:

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) drawerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu mm = navigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem m = mm.findItem(R.id.nav_regular_menu_item;
        m.setChecked(true);
    }
```

But how do I get to a nested menu item, to set it checked for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a Group with android:checkableBehaviour="single" around the Items and then `navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_gallery).setChecked(true);` should work for you.

```
<item android:title="View options">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/submenu"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:title="Gallery"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                android:title="Slideshow"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
```